# What is the word for the action of stepping on the floor to get something off of one's feet?

Tags: word-request

Let's say there is a lot of snow outside. I came in, but my boots are covered in snow. How do you call this action when you want something to not be one your feet? Does "stomp my feet" or "stamp my feet" communicate that meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> I stomped the snow off my shoes.

The action of stomping (treading heavily) is what removes the snow from your shoes, and that would be clearly understood. It would be much like saying:

> I shook the snow off my shoes.

or

> I scraped the snow off my shoes.

All give a verb to show an action and an intended result.